# Type of "this" object within "new" operator

Tags: javascript, object

I've little confused by javascript's "new" operator. How I know "new SomeClass()" has behaviour like that:

```
_instance = {};
_instance.__proto__ = SomeClass.prototype;
return SomeClass.apply(_instance, arguments) || _instance;
```

And as a return we have "SomeClass {}", i.e. SomeClass's instance.
But if I want to see what is "this" within constructor function:

```
A = function(){ console.log(this); };
new A;
```

I see *A {}* in output. 
So, how "new" operator creates _instance empty object, that it's already an object with A-type?

---

```
var A = function(){ console.log(this); };
var _instance = {}
_instance.__proto__ = A.prototype;
A.apply(_instance) || _instance;
```

Will log *Object {}* not a *A {}*. 
As I understand, we can't achieve same behavior that "new" have?

Comment: So what is the actual question? I didnt get it.

Comment: Maybe [new Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2) would shed some light on how it works?

Comment: What is the question. Can you show the full code?

Comment: @Teemu that's not the simplest way to introduce it to someone. [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is probably clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new JavaScript Object using new keyword, JavaScript adds a property named `constructor` which has a `name` attribute in it:

```
var a = new A();
console.log(a.constructor===A);//true
```

and what you actually see as a name in console it is just the name property of that function:

```
console.log(a.constructor.name);//"A"
```

whereas when you create a literal object like:

```
var _instance = {};
```

the constructor is the JavaScript `Object` class:

```
console.log(_instance.constructor===Object);//true
console.log(_instance.constructor.name);//"Object"
```

The other point is, no matter which way you use to create your object, you could always check it like:

```
_instance instanceof _instance.constructor
```

The other point is related to some extra magic works which usually JavaScript consoles do. For instance in Chrome, even when the function is a nameless function like:

```
var A = function/*function name should be here*/(){};
//you can check it like:
console.log(A.name);//""
```

Chrome checks the name on that object an if it is an empty string, it uses the function's variable name instead of the `constructor.name`.

Then what happens if there were no variable for that function, like when you create your object like:

```
var obj=new (function(){});
//output is Object {}
```

then since there is no variable created for that function, and it doesn't have any name, `console` has no other choice other than using `Object` as that name in the output, whereas if you name it like:

```
var obj=new (function FunctionName(){});
//console output is FunctionName {}
```

it uses the function's name and outputs it like: `FunctionName {}`

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear. Chrome's console just to smart) Tried in Firefox, it get's "Object" for "new", like it should be I belive

Answer (score 0):

It's a new object of type `A`, not named `A`.

Answer (score 0):

New operator is basically used with constructor function to create instances.

This is what a new operator does essentially :

1) creates an instance of Object function

2) calls the constructor function with the created object,(this object inside constructor is nothing but reference to the created object by new operator)

3) returns the created object.

The below e.g. is to give you implementation idea of it.

```
function f() {
    this.name = "hello";
}

f.prototype = {
    getName : function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

function instance(func) {
    var obj = new Object;
    func.call(obj);
    obj.__proto__ = f.prototype;
    return obj; 
}

a = instance(f);
```

The benefit of using new operator is that you can introspect type of object at runtime using instanceOf operator.

```
a instanceOf Object -> true
a instanceOf f -> true
```